# Open Modal in semantic-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I just cant figure out how to open this modal. I usually use Bootstrap, but wanted to try a new layout.

Here is the button that I use to open the Modal:

```
<div class="ui pointing menu">
        <a class="item" id="#register">Register</a>
        @include('auth.modals')
</div>
```

Here is my Modal:

```
<div id="register-modal" class="ui modal">
    <i class="close icon"></i>
    <div class="header">
        Profile Picture
    </div>
    <div class="image content">
        <div class="ui medium image">
            <img src="">
        </div>
        <div class="description">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <div class="ui black deny button">
            Nope
        </div>
        <div class="ui positive right labeled icon button">
            Yep, that's me
            <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And Here is my JavaScript:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#register').click(function(){
                    $('#register-modal').modal('show');
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Figured it out!

I guess the button that you open the modal with has to be a class?

```
  <a class="item register">Register</a>
```

Then pass in JavaScript like this:

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.register').click(function(){
                    $('#register-modal').modal('show');
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: that's not true, you can reference to the button in any way you want, id, class or just look it up in the DOM, or use knockout... or anything else. The problem was with your id in the original code.

Comment: dude, how come you moved the accepted answer to this one, as first of all it's totally wrong, and second of all you already admitted, the other one pointed the real issue. What a mess. Try to read the regulations first.

Answer (score 4):

The whole problem is that the element to which you try to attach the click event does not exist. You have specified `id="#register"`, instead of `id="register"`

correcting the attribute will do the job:

```
<div class="ui pointing menu">
        <a class="item" id="register">Register</a>
        @include('auth.modals')
</div>
```

The id of the modal itself seems to be correct, though :)

Such things are very easy to debug, simply type `$('#register')` in the console, and you'll see that jquery cannot find any matching element.

Comment: Oh my, I did not catch that mistake!